# conflicts with home internet and VPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, routing

Sorry for my English.

I have a usb modem through which I go out to the Internet.  I want to connect via VPN to the corporative network. The connection is successful. The corporation portal works okay, but I can't to connect to various servers via rdp (or other services). This is my routes without vpn(on Russian language, sorry):
[image]

This is routes with the vpn:
[image]

I think the problem is that the provider of the modem and the corporate network(gateway address:192.168.0.1) use the same netmask. How to solve it?

PS. When VPN is connected the Internet works okay.
PS2. I use the Kerio VPN Client.

Comment: You need to speak to your internal IT team.

Comment: Please provide the IP address you are trying to connect to.

Comment: @Dan: They are don't know. Very "good" IT team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far i can see, there is no direct problem with your local network and the VPN. Your local network uses the 192.168.0.x ip range and the VPN is using the 10.253.2.x range.

The netmask is OK to the the same, the base network address is the one that should not be the same (that aren't, as i said above)

I suspect the problem might be the DNS or some firewall (yours or theirs).

To debug, try to ping a internal server name on the corporative network (something like the file server. please be sure that it work on the corporative network, to ensure its valid) and will get 1 of this 3 output:

```
 C:\temp>ping file-server.company.com
 Ping request could not find host file-server.company.com . Please check the name and try again.
```

This will tell you that you aren't resolving the corporative DNS. It may be because it's not configured by the vpn or its blocked. Do a `ipconfig /all` to see if you have DNS setup in the vpn internet. If yes, then it's a firewall, if not, then it's the VPN that isn't configuring the DNS

another possible output is:

```
 C:\temp>ping file-server.company.com
 Pinging file-server.company.com [10.253.2.10] with 32 bytes of data:
```

This tell you that the DNS is working (you get one IP), but can't ping the server. It's most probably a firewall problem or a vpn routing problem on the corporative network. A `tracert file-server.company.com` might help seeing where the IP packages are being lost.

If the ping command also show this:

```
 Reply from 10.253.2.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
```

then you are connected, have working DNS and routing. If you still can't use the remote servers, then it's for sure a firewall problem (or the service is blocked for the VPN ip
range)

If the DNS fail, try to repeat this tests, but with the IP address of the server. If the IP is outside the range 10.253.2.[1-254], then your VPN isn't setting up the route for those networks.

vpn usually are hard to debug, so take baby steps, testing each part of the vpn. i'm assuming that the vpn is really working as you have the VPN ip. For each problem found, you will need to talk to the IT team, showing then the test results, so help then debug the problem with you.